# Angularjs $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Amigos, sou novo no AngularJS e estou precisando da vossa ajuda.

É o seguinte, eu estou fazendo um *request* via `$http` do AngularJS, consigo obter os dados tudo certinho, mas preciso fazer o `post` com os dados que eu requisitei no `$http.get()`.

Alguém que já tenha precisado fazer isso poderia me dar uma ajuda? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize dentro do callback `success` do get:

```
$http.get("api/endpoint").success(function(data){
    // a partir daqui utilize a variável "data" em seu post
    $http({method:'POST', url:'api/endpoint2', data:data}).success(function(data){
        ...
    });
});
```

Uma outra solução é salvar o restorno do get em `$scope` e utiliza-lo mais tarde quando necessário.

```
$http.get("api/endpoint").success(function(data){
   $scope.retornoDoGet = data; 
});
...
$http({method:'POST', url:'api/endpoint2', data:$scope.retornoDoGet}).success(function(data){
    ....
});
```

Comment: Obrigado! consegui fazer funcionar!

Answer (score 0):

O que eu recomendaria nesse caso, seria utilizar 2 funções separadas. Uma para cada `$http` que você precisar fazer. Isso irá dar mais liberdade, inclusive no reuso do código.

Ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
function http1() {
    return $http.get('seu/caminho/arquivo.json').then(
        function (response) { 
            outroHttp(response); 
        },
        function (err) { alert('Alerta de erro'); }
    );
};

function outroHttp(data) {
    return $http.post('seu/caminho/arquivo.php', data).then(
        function (response) {
            //Seu tratamento de dados aqui
        },
        function (err) { alert('Alerta de erro'); }
    );
};
```

Deste modo, você pode chamar a função tanto através de uma função vinda do DOM:

```
<div ng-click="chamaHttp1()">Chama Função 01</div>
```

e no controller:

```
$scope.chamaHttp1 = http1();
```

Ou fazer o reuso dentro do próprio controller, seguindo a mesma lógica usada na função `http1()`.